# Why is my userLocation.location always nil?

Tags: swift, mkmapview

I have mkmapview delegate to handle authorization events, etc., however, my userLocation is real, but my userLocation.location always returns nil in simulator or on device.

Any pointers on why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be sure you have added :

```
NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription in your info.plist project file

Register for CLLocationManagerDelegate

mapView.showsUserLocation=YES;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
      [super viewDidLoad];
      locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
      [locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
      [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}
```

Hope it will help

Test this behavior on your device is Simpler ( or don't forget to set a location in your simulator configuration )

Comment: I was using latest Xcode and Swift3 and added: "Privacy - Location Always Usage Description" to the plist with my text. And that made it all work. Thanks!